# CollapsingToolbarLayout also collapse Toolbar when using with RecyclerView when scrolling up

Tags: android

`CollapsingToolbarLayout` also collapse `Toolbar` when using with `RecyclerView` when scrolling up

I don't want to make `Toolbar`(`ActionBar`) disappear when scrolling screen up or while collapsing within `AppBarLayout`.

I am using `CoordinatorLayout`.

Following is my layout file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_pic_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/PrimaryColor"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
                android:title=" "
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:background="@color/PrimaryColor"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/check_icon"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/check_sm"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </FrameLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" >


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/projectName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/MainFragmentTicketItemAccount"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="Project Name"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/list_text_size"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/labelProjectNo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="@string/lbl_project_no"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/label_color" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/projectNo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                            android:text="657894512"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/labelAccountName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/lbl_account_name"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/label_color" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/accountName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:text="Aqui del carlos"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/labelstartDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/start_date"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/label_color" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/startDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:text="25-06-2016"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/labelEndDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/acc5"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/label_color" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/endDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:text="30-06-2016"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/labelpadidod_no"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/lbl_padido_no"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/label_color" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/padidoNo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:text="4581233"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl_installation_no"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/lbl_installation_no"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/label_color" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/installationNo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:text="4581233"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl_status"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/status"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/label_color" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/status"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:text="Activo"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
                
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView123"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/arrow_up_circle"/>
    </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/simpleRecyclerView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainFragmentEmptyLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="194dp"
            android:layout_width="253dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_main_no_data"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_data1"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/info_no_data_color"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_data2"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textColor="@color/info_no_data_color"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

while scrolling appBar it should be fixed when reached to toolbar height, so i need toolbar fixed at its position.

thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My requirement is something different from other SO question that is toolBar not collapsing etc but in my case i don't wanted to collapse my toolBar while scrolling up and collapsing appBar,

So i came up with following solution, this will help someone with similar issue.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/PrimaryColor"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">
```

following couple line of code solved my issue.

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
```